# Navigation Icons in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress

I installed a new theme in WordPress and I found the navigation/menu for this theme in mobile view is Icons Menu not horizontal menu as in normal browsers view

Check this picture:
http://oi58.tinypic.com/2q3xaw0.jpg

Which part in the theme files is responsible for this issue?
CSS? or any other php file?

Comment: Check the theme's style.css and look for media queries, or perhaps the theme has a responsive.css etc.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome right click the menu bar and select "Inspect Element".

Now you can inspect the elements on the page and see what ID or Class they have.

Search the Theme folder for a file called custom.css, here you can add new css styles that will override the old ones. Now you can redesign the menu bar as you like.

Or,

There may be a menu setting in the wp-admin backend of wordpress. Check the wordpress sidebar on the left for a new item named 'your theme' and search the options for menu settings, you may be able to check a button to change it there.